# Visual Force Tags

Tags: apex, visualforce

what is the use of apex:param tag in Visual Force

```
<apex:outputLink value="http://google.com/search">

    Search Google

    <apex:param name="q" value="{!contact.name}"/>

</apex:outputLink>
```

If i click Preview in Visual Force page it is simply linked to contacts page,how the tag is working?please explain with example

Comment: This example is already explained in Salesforce documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_query_params_setting.htm

Comment: I dont able to understand , what is the use of <apex:param> tag then why they are giving !q what is that meaning, which value it is taking

Comment: Okay, see my explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `name` & `value` attribute of `<apex:param` will form a `key value pair` parameter appended to the URL. See the below example, which represents with param and without param. The `name` attribute `q` and `value` attribute `account.name` forms the `?q={!account.name}` appended to the URL.

[image]